# JavaScript Star Rating System

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a working star rating system, but If a user has already voted and changes their mind on the vote, they cannot reset their vote.

Here is what I have in the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var set = false;
var v = 0;
var a;

function loadStars() {
    star1 = new Image();
    star1.src = "images/star1.png";
    star2 = new Image();
    star2.src = "images/star2.png";
}

function highlight(x) {
    if (set == false) {
        y = x * 1 + 1
        switch (x) {
        case "1":
            document.getElementById(x).src = star2.src;
            document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "One star";
            break;
        case "2":
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star2.src;
            }
            document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "Two stars"
            break;
        case "3":
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star2.src;
            }
            document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "Three stars"
            break;
        case "4":
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star2.src;
            }
            document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "Four stars"
            break;
        case "5":
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star2.src;
            }
            document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "Five stars"
            break;
        }
    }
}

function losehighlight(x) {
    if (set == false) {
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            document.getElementById(i).src = star1.src;
            document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = ""
        }
    }
}

function setStar(x) {
    y = x * 1 + 1
    if (set == false) {
        switch (x) {
        case "1":
            a = "1"
            flash(a);
            break;
        case "2":
            a = "2"
            flash(a);
            break;
        case "3":
            a = "3"
            flash(a);
            break;
        case "4":
            a = "4"
            flash(a);
            break;
        case "5":
            a = "5"
            flash(a);
            break;
        }
        set = true;
        insertrating(x, '<?=$themeid?>');
        document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "Thank you!";
    }

    function flash() {
        y = a * 1 + 1
        switch (v) {
        case 0:
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star1.src;
            }
            v = 1
            setTimeout(flash, 200)
            break;
        case 1:
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star2.src;
            }
            v = 2
            setTimeout(flash, 200)
            break;
        case 2:
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star1.src;
            }
            v = 3
            setTimeout(flash, 200)
            break;
        case 3:
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star2.src;
            }
            v = 4
            setTimeout(flash, 200)
            break;
        case 4:
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star1.src;
            }
            v = 5
            setTimeout(flash, 200)
            break;
        case 5:
            for (i = 1; i < y; i++) {
                document.getElementById(i).src = star2.src;
            }
            v = 6
            setTimeout(flash, 200)
            break;
        }
    }

</script>
```

How would I go about allowing the user to resubmit a vote?

My html looks like this:

```
<span style="float: left; text-align: left;"> Rate This Theme<br />
    <img src="images//star1.png" onMouseOver="highlight(this.id)" onClick="setStar(this.id)" onMouseOut="losehighlight(this.id)" id="1" style="float: left;" /> 
    <img src="images/star1.png" onMouseOver="highlight(this.id)" onClick="setStar(this.id)" onMouseOut="losehighlight(this.id)" id="2" style="float: left;" /> 
    <img src="images/star1.png" onMouseOver="highlight(this.id)" onClick="setStar(this.id)" onMouseOut="losehighlight(this.id)" id="3" style="float: left;" /> 
    <img src="images/star1.png" onMouseOver="highlight(this.id)" onClick="setStar(this.id)" onMouseOut="losehighlight(this.id)" id="4" style="float: left;" /> 
    <img src="images/star1.png" onMouseOver="highlight(this.id)" onClick="setStar(this.id)" onMouseOut="losehighlight(this.id)" id="5" style="float: left;" /> 
</span>
```

Comment: I assume you copied this code from somewhere?  It's pretty bad...

Comment: I am mending a web page, which was previously outsourced.  Im very close to scrapping this.

Comment: Wow; outsource some work to me! If I can get paid for producing stuff like this, **sign me up**!

Comment: I usually don't nitpick code if you don't ask for it, but they are right, it is pretty bad. I'm sure JQuery has some plugins for star ratings, probably worth looking into.

Comment: I think I will scrap. Already on that road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only thing preventing the user from re-voting is your `set` variable.

```
   if (set==false)
   {
   ...  
   set=true;
```

Just get rid of the `if` clause and it should run even if `set==true`

Per Tomalak's comment, i forgot to mention that:

> If the backend doesn't support this,
>   then it will insert a new vote rather
>   than changing the existing one. And
>   since there doesn't appear to be any
>   user identification, that would appear
>   to be the case

If you don't have any user authentication, at least use a cookie or something to keep track of which user is what so that the vote is edited, not a new one created.

As for setting cookies, I'd recommend setting a cookie via Javascript once the user votes the first time. On the backend, whatever you're using for server-side technology should check to see if a cookie already exists, and if it does, edit the ranking entry instead of creating a new one. 
Here's a good resource on cookies in JS: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Yea, the set variable is initially what tweaked me.  I will play with that a bit more.

Comment: -1 If the backend doesn't support this, then it will insert a new vote rather than changing the existing one. And since there doesn't appear to be any user identification, that would appear to be the case.

Comment: @Tomalak Arggh i was going to mention that and forgot. thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

> **bootstrap V4 font-awesome pro jquery**

```
$('.starts i').click(function(){
$('.starts i').removeClass('fas').addClass('fal');
var sindex=$('.starts i').index(this);
    for(var i=0;i<=sindex;i++){
        $('.starts i').eq(i).removeClass('fal').addClass('fas');
    }
})

<div class="starts h4 mt-3" style="color:#FBC02D">
<span class=" ml-2"><i class="fal fa-star"></i></span>
<span class="checked ml-2 title"><i class="fal fa-star"></i></span>
<span class="checked ml-2"><i class="fal fa-star"></i></span>
<span class="checked ml-2"><i class="fal fa-star"></i></span>
<span class="checked ml-2"><i class="fal fa-star"></i></span>
</div>
```